# What generates the Symfony/SensioLabs Documentation PDFs

Tags: php, symfony, pdf, twig, silex

It doesn't seem to be anywhere in the documentations themselves, nor on the website. Google is failing me, and I can't access IRC currently.

What makes the nice looking documentation pdf for the SensioLabs products?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its topic, general tooling, isn't included in the [on topic list](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) of StackOverflow.

Comment: Close it if you must, but I would like to point out that this isn't about general tooling, it is about what I assumed to be a specific feature or a symfony component that wasn't documented(it barely is apparently). It also seems to me that Sphinx is a  ***software tools commonly used by programmers;*** and ***is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development*** like the guidelines say. I can edit the question if necessary, as I think this is useful to other people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs are built using [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org), a documentation tool on top of the reStructured Text format.

This tool allows one to compile the source as a HTML output, resulting in the docs shown on [symfony.com/doc](http://symfony.com/doc). It also has a PDF builder, which outputs the docs in the PDF files.

Comment: Thank you! The only place it seems to be mentioned is on the contributing page. This has been driving me nuts.